# How to test if a specific string exists in array

Tags: javascript

Good evening, I am trying to find a way to Search for specific strings in an array, where the strings all on different lines.

Here is my code

```
this.importDataObject("MEDDIAGNOSISICD-10.txt", "C:/Users/dell/Documents/tab 
excel/MEDDIAGNOSISICD-10.txt");
var oFile = this.getDataObjectContents("MEDDIAGNOSISICD-10.txt");
var cFile = util.stringFromStream(oFile, "utf-8");
var fileArray = cFile.split('\n');
var Med = this.getField("Medications 1");
var CodeOne = this.getField("ICD 10 CODE 2 PGX");
var Index = fileArray.indexOf(Med.value);
var Call = fileArray[Index];

var i, Index;
for (i = 0; i < fileArray.length; i++) {  
  Index = fileArray[i].indexOf(Med.value);
  if(Index > -1) Cartographer = fileArray[i].split('\t');
  if(Index > -1) MedAnalysis = Cartographer[0];
  if(Index > -1) BrandAnalysis = Cartographer[1];
  if(Index > -1) DiagAnalysis = Cartographer[2];
  if(Index > -1) CodeAnalysis = Cartographer[3];
  if(Index > -1) CodeSearch = CodeAnalysis.search("F33.0");  
  if(Index > -1 && CodeSearch != -1) CodeOne = "F33.0";
  if(Index > -1) console.println(CodeSearch);
}
```

The results if you print out CodeSearch are -1, and 0, on separate lines.
How can I search ALL the lines in the Array, or at least be able to see if the F33.0 can be scanned for first.

Comment: JS doesn't allow line breaks in strings. The string beginning with `"C:` should be all on one line.

Comment: What do you mean by "the strings all on different lines"? Different lines of what?

Comment: You can just use `array.includes(stringYouWantToSearchFor)`

Comment: @Barmar, the array is built from a textfile split on the line breaks. I think that's what it refers to.

Comment: Why do you keep repeating `if(Index > -1)`? Put all the code in a single `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use the array `find` method:

```
var fileLine = fileArray.find(line => line.includes(Med.value) && line.includes("F33.0"));
if (fileLine) {
    [MedAnalysis, BrandAnalysis, DiagAnalysis, CodeAnalysis] = fileLine.split("\t");
    if (CodeAnalysis.includes("F33.0")) {
        CodeOne = "F33.0";
    }
}
```